# smoothState.js and dynamic urls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can get pages to load properly with ajax/animations when links are simple like "about.php" or contact.php", but smoothState is having trouble when I am trying to use it from search results / product pages.

For example from "search.php?clearSearch=true&searchPhrase=blue" to "product/27/Product-Blue.html" it looks like it tries to load for a short while (cursor style changes) and then after a second or so gives up and reloads the page with the new url.